# Jquery form plugin is ignoring ajaxSetup settings

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to use `$.ajaxSetup()` to set global data to be sent in every ajax request.

According to [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2131-Using-jQuery-ajaxSetup-To-Accumulate-Global-Data-Parameters-For-AJAX-Requests.htm), what I am trying should works fine.

However, some of the ajax calls in my app are forms using the form plugin. Those calls doesnt seems to include the data I set in `$.ajaxSetup()`. I believe it's also using jquery `$.ajax()` , but it just simply doesnt work. So I am write to ask if there's some way to achieve it.

Here's a demo page to show what I am trying to do.
http://jsfiddle.net/FSLyA/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reviewing the code of the form plugin, I have found that the plugin looks up all form elements and create a query string with those data, which overwrites the `data` object set in 
`$.ajaxSetup()`. And so the trick doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry i fail to see how this is a solution to his problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your jsfiddle example is not the same thing as the blog post.

You are just using the vanilla URL of google, yahoo etc... - what do you expect to happen? An ajax call will not just send back that page no matter if you use a form or anything else to send data to it. The purpose of an ajax call is to get the other part (the server side script) to process your data and send some data back.

I assume your example was not the real code you are using. Perhaps you could post that?

Also it might be that the same domain policy is coming into play, or that actually your whole understanding of Ajax is limited at the moment. I'm not sure which it is.

Comment: Ok I should have explain what my example is used for. You by clicking different buttons, you can see the generated xhr using browser developer tools like google's. And only the form submit using the form plugin is missing the data I set using `$.ajaxSetup()`